# Zeros of special Dirichlet series.

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

There is given Dirichlet series:
$$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$$
$$f(x+iy)=\eta(x+iy)\eta(x-iy)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^{x+iy}}$$
Where $a(n)=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+\frac{n}{d}}d^{2yi}$ And of course $x>0$.

Let's consider $g(x,y)=\frac{d^{2}f(x+iy)}{dx^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln n)^{2}a(n)}{n^{x+iy}}$.

My question: **Is that function always non negative**?

I made some research and i deduced that for $x>0$ small enough function $g(x,y)$ is positive hence for constant $y$ if there would be negative value, then it would exist some $x$ that:

$$g(x,y)=0$$

Regards.

Comment: What is meant by "it must not have Dirichlet character"?

Comment: It means that $$a(n)$$ may be Dirichlet character or not.

Comment: Dirichlet Series are with $\;\{a_n\}\;$ **any** complex sequence.  Why would you stress that it could or could not be a Dirichlet character?